# The new child element contains the parent. at HTMLDivElement.drop

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I am stuck with this DOM exception. I have div elements and a button - when the user clicks on the button a random div is chosen on which another div is appended. This another div has a class with background-color set on it. In other words, when user clicks the button a random div container is filled with another random colored div. Then I want the user to be able to drag this newly created and colored div to an empty one. This is where the problem comes in. Here is my markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="empty border"></div>
    <div class="empty border"></div>
    <div class="empty border"></div>
    <div class="empty border"></div>
    <div class="empty border"></div>
    <div class="empty border"></div>
</div>
```

After the button is clicked (a new div is appended) it looks like this:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="empty border"></div>
    <div class="empty border">
        <div class="filled" draggable="true" id="test
        style="background-color: rgb(242, 202, 185);"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="empty border"></div>
    <div class="empty border"></div>
    <div class="empty border"></div>
    <div class="empty border"></div>
 </div>
```

So, when the "filled" div is being droped in the dropzone (an empty div) I get this uncaught exception. Here is my JS:

```
const prepareForDrag =  () => {
let divElements = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('div'));
let emptyCubes = divElements.filter(cube =>    cube.classList.contains('empty'));
let filledCubes = divElements.filter(cube => cube.classList.contains('filled'));

emptyCubes.forEach(function (cube) {
    cube.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
    cube.addEventListener('drop', drop);
})

filledCubes.forEach(function (cube) {
    cube.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
})

function dragStart (e) {
    emptyCubes.forEach(cube => cube.classList.add('dropzone-border'));
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.target.getAttribute('id'));
}

function dragOver (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}


function drop (e) {
    let coloredCube = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
    e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(coloredCube));
    emptyCubes.forEach(cube => cube.classList.remove('dropzone-border'));
}
}
```

What I clearly understand is that when I release the mouse button it tries to append both the parent div and the "filled" one, but I really can't find a solution. Any help and brutal criticism will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. 
I am saving the current dragged div in the `dragged` variable and I put a `drop` event on the entire document, then you can use that dragged variable to remove it from the it's parent node and append to the dropped element.

I think you either have multiple elements with the same `id` that is confusing Javascript or the `coloredCube` variable you have in the drop function isn't returning the value you think it is. I'd put a console.log on coloredCube. I am getting an empty string when I run the `getData` method on the dataTransfer property which could be resulting in the error you're getting.

```
let dragged;

function appendDiv(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const emptyDivs = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('empty'));
    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.classList = 'filled';
    newDiv.draggable = true;
    newDiv.style.backgroundColor="red";
    newDiv.style.height = "50px";
    newDiv.style.width = "50px";
    newDiv.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
    newDiv.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);
    // Should add to a random empty div. I just picked one to add it.
    emptyDivs[1].appendChild(newDiv); 
}

function dragStart(e){
    dragged = e.target;
    e.target.style.opacity = .5;
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', null);
}

function dragEnd(e){
    e.target.style.opacity = "";
}

function handleDrop(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    dragged.parentNode.removeChild(dragged);
    e.target.appendChild(dragged);
}

function dragOver(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}

document.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop);

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('empty')).forEach(emptyDiv => {
    emptyDiv.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
});


document.getElementById('btn-append').addEventListener('click', appendDiv);
```

Comment: Yes, the problem was that in a particular moment a second id with the same name was added to a random div(part of my code that I didn't share yesterday). Regarding to the empty string that you get, isn't  that the way it works? I mean isn't dataTransfer.setData() protected by the JS engine or I am wrong?